# Run Powershell Script from ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script from an asp.net web application. I have setup the execution policy to 'Remotesigned" but even after that when I hosted my web application in IIS I am getting "Running script on this system is disabled"
How can I resolve this error.
Thanks,

Comment: What are the rights of the application pool associated to your asp.net application? Set it to admin to test (and only to test!) that things work (or not). If they do, you know this is a right problem.

Comment: I have setup the application pool identity to use the Domain Admin credentials but even after that the powershell  script is not running from web application. I am able to run it successfully from visual studio debug option.